# WPF Application Indefinite progress bar doesn't show but processes are running on background

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, async-await

As I got the processes to work I ran onto possibly a Threading problem when I was trying to add a ProgressBar to give the user some clue that the process hasn't crashed. Since this is enough, an Indefinite ProgressBar in just fine for me.

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="ProcessProgress" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Visibility="Hidden" IsIndeterminate="False" Width="305" Height="20" Margin="240,214,248,10"></ProgressBar>
```

I tried to initiate a determinate length progress bar which is not visible before the Start button is clicked :

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    //process starts here
    var fP = new FileProcessor();
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
    ProcessProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    ...
    //finally show the progressbar as full when done
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = false;
    ProcessProgress.Value = ProcessProgress.Maximum;

}
```

It just runs the whole process and my bar doesn't show up.

How can I spawn a progress bar during the process ?

Comment: async await is the way to go. you shouldn't do the actual operations on the code behind anyways. It should be done thru ViewModel + command pattern. I know its lots of things to learn but if you gonna do it, better do it right :)

Comment: @Steve Yes, you are totally correct and I appreciate the gesture. May I ask for a proper tip(maybe a link or bibliography, series of videos)? I'd like to get involved pretty fast since at the beginning of next month I need to connect it to an SQL server and none of my group partners actually have fingers to code(if you know what I mean) .

Comment: keywords: "MVVM", "WPF ICommand", "async await", "c# Task". google the tutorial for those and get a good understanding of what they are and how to properly use them then you are good to start. Might take 2+ weeks to finish everything. Sql will take months to master so just keep that in mind.

Comment: I cannot say if this will work for your particular case, but see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212664/7692463) where I talk about this particular topic.

Comment: @scharette Thank you for your Comment. I'll take a peak soon and hopefully it will pay dividens, since we are really really really running out of time. :(

Comment: @VargaElőd I'll will post a boiler plate for you removing the unnecessary stuff of the linked answer.

Comment: @scharette Huge thanks, I'll stay on alert this evening. Would be nice if I could get atleast the prototype up and running tomorrow morning.

Comment: @VargaElőd before saying "thank you", that code has multiple serious bugs. You *don't* need that extension at all, the code before and after `await Task.Run()` runs on the UI thread. Just modify the progress bar. `async void` should only be used for event handlers, never for other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all of your code runs in the UI thread. The UI has no chance to update itself before the entire process finishes.

You can use `Task.Run()` to run a heavy job in the background without blocking the UI. You can use the `await` keyword to await that task to complete without blocking the UI. Once the task completes, you are back in the UI thread where you can modify the UI again.

A quick and dirty fix for this event handler would be :

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
    ProcessProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      ...
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        //process starts here
        var fP = new FileProcessor();

        ...
    });

    //We are back in the UI thread, we can modify the UI
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = false;
    ProcessProgress.Value = ProcessProgress.Maximum;
}
```

No need to use `Invoke` to get back to the UI thread, that's the job of `await` itself.

A note about `async void`. It's *ONLY* meant for event handlers or similar methods. You *can't* await an `async void` method which means you can't even get any exceptions if something goes wrong. Asynchronous methods that return nothing should have the `async Task` signature.

If you want to report progress you can use the [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and the [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). The Progress class will call a callback or raise an event on the thread it was created. The payload can be any class, not just a percentage

It's best to move the reporting code to *separate* methods, to keep the button handler clean. The code can look like this :

```
//The progress class
class FileProgress
{
    public string FileName{get;set;}
    public int Progress{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}

    public FileProgress(string fileName,int progress,string message)
    {
        FileName=filename;
        Progress=progress;
        Message=message;
    }
}

//In the form itself
private void ReportStart()
{
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
    ProcessProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void ReportEnd()
{
    ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = false;
    ProcessProgress.Value = ProcessProgress.Maximum;
}

private void ReportProgress(FileProgress progress)
{
    ProcessProgress.Value =progress.Progress;        
    PanelStatus.Text = $"Working on {progress.FileName} : {progress.Message}";
}
```

The event handler can now look like this :

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReportStart();

    IProgress<FileProgress> progress=new Progress<FileProgress>(ReportProgress);
      ...
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        //process starts here
        var fP = new FileProcessor();

        foreach(var file in someFiles)
        {
              progress.Report(new FileProgress(file,0,"Starting");
              //Do some processing
              progress.Report(new FileProgress(file,100,"Finished");
        }
        ...
    });

    //We are back in the UI thread, we can modify the UI
    ReportEnd();
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the moment I should really say thank you. Implementing this approach eliminated all my bugs and now I have only one thing to solve which is another question to be asked. Huge ups for this answer, Sir.